# What's the command line equivalent of alt F1?

Tags: terminal

I wrote a bunch of shell script functions to switch between 3 different OSs I have on Raspberry Pi so that I could use Siri/homebridge to switch between them.

I was testing everything out while I was ssh'ed in and I watched things happen on the TV the RPi is connected to via HDMI.

Everything works great except when I use any of the "stop" functions to exit out of any of the 3 OSs to get back to the console.  The OSs (either Kodi, emulationstation/retropie, or raspbian) all stop fine, but I'm not kicked out to the console.  All I get is a black screen.

I discovered, after an inordinate amount of time to get the right google search terms, that I can type alt+F1 to be able to see the console on the TV.

My question is, what can I put in my shell script functions to do this programmatically?  I.e. What's the command line equivalent of alt+F1?

Comment: Not sure that function keys are coded the same across all OS's, but [this might help.](https://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the **chvt** utility.

`$ sudo chvt 1`

Comment: hmmm... It didn't work the first time I tried it.  I had to run `sudo chvt 2` first (which showed a login prompt on the screen).  Then executing `sudo chvt 1` returned me to the familiar console screen.  I tried it a couple times. Is there anything I need to do before `sudo chvt 1` to make it work? I suspect that this situation is caused by `export DISPLAY=":0"` which I need to do in order to start kodi via ssh...

Comment: The VTs are a kernel thing. X11 isn't involved, the Xserver just occupies one of the VTs. You asked about Alt+F1, so that's the same as `chvt 1` does.

Comment: I guess the reason why it doesn't work is you are in VT1, but it's set to a weird mode. A VT switch will re-initialize it. What you could do is assign each of the systems a different VT and simply switch between them and the VT console.

Comment: It must have to do with the way I’m killing kodi/emulationstation/raspbian. I’ll mark your answer and ask a separate question.